# Python pandas, filling in data's from DF1 to DF2 and create a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

enter code here`I have two dataframes
df1, which contains the Item / Date and Quantity to deliver:
[image: df.1]

df2 the stock and WIP:
[image: df2]

I would like to compare the same "Item" and deduct the stock from the "quantity needed", once "stock" =0 and "quantity needed" > 0, then my "WIP" will start deducting until the "quantity needed" is 0, if both "stock" and "WIP" runs out then insert "planned" within the cell.

Also if either "stock" or "WIP" runs out, create a new row that has the remaining value of "quantity needed" with the same "delivery date".

expected out-put:
[image: expected out-out]

I'm fairly new to coding and have been struggling for weeks on this little project, a lot of people told me to give up, but I just couldn't let go.

Anyone can give me an idea or direction?
pandas? numpy?

Right, my apologize for not adding this information within

```
#DF1
data1 = [["Apple", "2021/1/1", 3], ["Apple", "2021/3/1", 2], ["Apple", "2021/7/1", 7], ["Banana", "2023/1/1", 10], ["Banana", "2023/12/1", 5], ["Banana", "2024/1/1", 3], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/1", 2], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/2", 1], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/3", 9], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/3", 20]
         ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Item', 'Date', "Quantity Remaining"])

#DF2
data2 = [["Apple", 2, 7], ["Banana", 10, 8], ["Kiwi", 10, 5]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=["Item", "Stock", "WIP"])

# Wanted Out-come

data3 = [["Apple", "2021/1/1", 2, "Stock"], ["Apple", "2021/1/1", 1, "WIP"], ["Apple", "2021/3/1", 2, "WIP"], ["Apple", "2021/7/1", 4, "WIP"], ["Apple", "2021/7/1", 3, "Planned"], ["Banana", "2023/1/1", 10, "Stock"], ["Banana", "2023/9/1", 6, "WIP"], ["Banana", "2023/12/1", 2, "WIP"], ["Banana", "2023/12/1", 3, "Planned"],
         ["Banana", "2024/1/1", 3, "Planned"], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/1", 2, "Stock"], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/1", 4, "Stock"], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/2", 1, "Stock"], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/3", 3, "Stock"], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/3", 5, "WIP"], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/3", 1, "Planned"], ["Kiwi", "2021/2/4", 20, "Planned"]]
outcome = pd.DataFrame(
    data3, columns=["Item", "Delivery Date", "Quantity", "Note"])
```

Comment: For input data (df1, df2), please provide the text (python code), you will make the life of the others easier.

Comment: You can use pandas to store your data, but pandas alone won't solve it for you. You then need to write the logic with loops. Loop over orders, see what's available and add one or several rows to your output depending on what fraction is available in stock, as WIP or has to be orderd, updating each time your view of the stocks. Does not seem very complicated really.

Comment: You should add those df1 & df2 data-frames here for better help , may be in excel sheet formats

Comment: I've just edited the df1 & df2 data-frames within the question above, sorry for not adding this earlier. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Could you kindly explain more about the concept?